# Android Studio set onclicklistener if arguments are true

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to make one button do different functions if arguments are true. For example:

Got many possibilities(Flexible UI)

```
public void BuildCars(View view)
{
    //Atver buildcarfragmentu.
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            ImageView Frame= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BCFrame);
            Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);

            Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BCButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL10_10());
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            break;
    }
}
```

In case 1, I want button to do one thing and in case 2 to do another thing.

Like here:

```
public void BuildCars(View view)
{
    //Atver buildcarfragmentu.
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            ImageView Frame= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BCFrame);
            Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);

            Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BCButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL10_10());
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.

            ImageView Frame= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BCFrame);
            Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);

            Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BCButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL9_4());
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            break;
    }
}
```

I have two problems:

Problem 1:

[image]

Problem 2:

[image]

Comment: Those aren't onClickListeners.  Those are methods.  You need to create a class that implements `View.OnClickListener` then pass that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your frame outside of the switch statement, perhaps in your BuildCars() method, rather than in each case of the Switch Statement. I.e:

```
public void BuildCars(View view)
{ 
    ImageView Frame= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BCFrame);
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BCButton);

    //Atver buildcarfragmentu.
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);

            button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL10_10());
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);
            button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL9_4());
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
            break;
    }
}
```

You're also using the on click listener incorrectly. Your listener should look more like this:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

You should read the documentation to gain a better understanding of how exactly use the onClickListener: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

From the images, these look like compilation errors

> Solution to Problem 1: Use block for each of your case statements

```
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1: { // <-- start block
       //do stuff
       break;
    } // <-- end block
    case R.id.button2: {
       //do stuff
       break;
    }
```

> Solution to Problem 2: It seems the method requires a `View` parameter

Try this

```
button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL10_10(someView));
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you want but in your code you create a new imageView and new Button in evry case why you dont try this ?

```
public void BuildCars(View view)
  {
          ImageView Frame= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BCFrame);
          Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BCButton);
   //Atver buildcarfragmentu.
    switch(view.getId())
   {
    case R.id.button1:

        Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);
        button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL10_10());
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
        Frame.setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);
        button.setOnClickListener(sellTiresLVL9_4());
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        // Set Frame Image, Part Cardviews and button.
        break;
     }
   }
```